# How do I manage this background image and the class's hover behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have an image that loads into a DIV:

```
.playerSkipForward
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

With hover image set

```
.playerSkipForward:hover
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward-hover.png");
}
```

Then at a certain point I add a class to it that changes the image and makes it look "inactive"

```
$(track).parents().find('.playerSkipForward').addClass('playerSkipForward_inactive')
```

The new (inactive) class is declared in my CSS like so

```
.playerSkipForward_inactive
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward_inactive.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

The image changes to the one in the class above correctly. However, it still hovers and changes colors. I do not want to add an unbinding like `.on('hover')` because bindings can be tricky to manage. Is there a way to override the hover with just the added css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comments I think this is an issue with [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Try using the following CSS class instead of your current `.playerSkipForward_inactive`:

```
.playerSkipForward.playerSkipForward_inactive,
.playerSkipForward.playerSkipForward_inactive:hover
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward_inactive.png");
    cursor: default;
}
```

Note I've also removed the `background-repeat` property. You already set the same value for this in your `.playerSkipForward` rule.

Comment: @frankie It's to do with CSS specificity. Look at the link in my answer or google it for more info. It's because your new CSS rule wasn't taken precedence over your existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
.playerSkipForward_inactive, .playerSkipForward_inactive:hover
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward_inactive.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: default;
}
```

If you're using two classes at once, try this more specific selector:

```
.playerSkipForward.playerSkipForward_inactive, 
.playerSkipForward.playerSkipForward_inactive:hover
    { 
    ...
    }
```

or the more common and simple:

```
.playerSkipForward.inactive, 
.playerSkipForward.inactive:hover
    { 
    ...
    }
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i tried but for some reason it still reverts to the original hover image even though it loads the new 'inactive' image fine while not hovering. any thoughts?

Comment: One possibility added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick. Just override the hover functionality for inactive state using `important` keyword.

```
.playerSkipForward_inactive:hover
{
    background-image: url("../images/player/forward_inactive.png") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    cursor: default !important;
}
```